# How to use Regular Expressions to select a single part of a file path

Tags: python, regex, filepath

I have a file path like this:

```
"C:/Users/myname/Documents/KF0_IFN_HLA_11.csv"
```

How could I use regular expressions to just get the `"KF0_IFN_HLA_11.csv"` part?

I'm a beginner to Python and I'm just looking for some tips about how to figure out the problem above.

Comment: If you just need the last part, you can use `os.path.basename`

Comment: Do you *have* to use regexp? Because there are better ways to do this.

Comment: No, I don't have to use regex. Do you mind telling me what better ways exist?

Comment: @nobodyAskedYouPatrice If you have to use regex, why does it matter that there are better ways? (like the one already listed)

Comment: Using regular expressions, it's simply this `[^/]*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 (not recommended):

Using `re.search` (`import re` first):

```
In [1099]: re.search(r'.*/(.*)$', text).group(1)
Out[1099]: 'KF0_IFN_HLA_11.csv'
```

The pattern is

```
r'.*/(.*)$'
```

It extracts the bit after the last forward slash.

---

Option 2 (recommended):

Using `os.path.split` or `os.path.basename` (`import os` first):

```
In [1100]: os.path.split(text)[1]
Out[1100]: 'KF0_IFN_HLA_11.csv'

In [1101]: os.path.basename(text)
Out[1101]: 'KF0_IFN_HLA_11.csv'
```

`os.path.split` splits the path into the head and tail, here you just extract the tail, because that's what you need.

`os.path.basename` returns the tail automatically.

Comment: @nobodyAskedYouPatrice Happy to help. I believe you should be aware of all your alternatives, so you know what not to use :)

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use regex for this, rather the `os.path` module is much more appropriate. Using `os.path.basename` will extract the file without the full path.

```
>>> import os
>>> p = r"C:/Users/myname/Documents/KF0_IFN_HLA_11.csv"
>>> os.path.basename(p)
'KF0_IFN_HLA_11.csv'
```